# Using ngmaps with json data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the ngmaps directive for ionic but it doesnt seem to display anything when i use it. I am trying to create the url with json data, it should be putting latitude and longitude into the map center but nothing shows up, not even the map.

```
<div id="gmap" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <div map-data="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"
        map-data-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}">
        <ng-map center="{{office.LatLong}}" zoom="3"></ng-map>
    </div> 



.controller('mapCtrl', function(NgMap, $scope) {
  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    console.log(map.getCenter());
    //console.log('markers', map.markers);
    //console.log('shapes', map.shapes);
    $scope.googleMapsUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBGAHnplGPjFoVvShk6Tsna3-DN8rHQBI8";
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8LbyY2TQ49jDsQaWRQe5?p=preview) based on [ngmap](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps):

There was a problem with your divs (not closing), here is the right sintax:

```
  <div id="gmap" >
      <div map-data="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" map-data-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}">
      <ng-map center="{{office.LatLong}}" zoom="4"></ng-map>
      </div>
  </div>
```